# Coproduct of graded modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, limits-colimits, graded-modules

Let $M=\oplus_{i\ge 0}M_i$ and $N=\oplus_{i\ge 0}N_i$ two graded modules over a commutative ring $R$. What is their coproduct? Is it their tensor product $M\otimes_k N$?

Thank you!

Comment: Please write what you tried.

Comment: My idea was that the tensor product is the coproduct in the category of commutative non-negative graded algebra. As there is an underlying structure of a graded module I thaught that the tensor product might as well be the coproduct of it.

Comment: The coproduct here works degreewise (like complexes), while the tensor product works (again) like the tensor product of complexes.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Can you be more explicit on this?

Comment: In which categories is the tensor product the coproduct?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the coproduct of modules over a ring is the direct sum?  (For the tensor product to be a coproduct, you want to be working in a category of commutative rings.)